# show and hide outer div when input is focus and not focus with css

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to control a div to hide and show only with css when the input is focused or not. But the problem is that the input I have is very deep in some element. How do I make the div show when the input is focused and the div hide when the input is not focused?

```css
.v-text-field input:focus-within > .class-target {
   display: block;
}

.class-target{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-input custom-search input-small v-text-field">
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">
      <div class="v-text-field__slot">
        <input id="input-17" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
      <div class="v-messages theme--light">
        <div class="v-messages__wrapper" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-target">Target</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="v-messages__wrapper" />` is invalid : Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the focus-within class

> :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused

Just remove the class from input. MDN DOC [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
.v-text-field:focus-within + .class-target {
   display: block;
}

.class-target{
   display: none;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-input custom-search input-small v-text-field">
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">
      <div class="v-text-field__slot">
        <input id="input-17" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
      <div class="v-messages theme--light">
        <div class="v-messages__wrapper">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-target">Target</div>
```